# Align a href to top of div text to a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to align an a tag to the top of my div in bootstrap. This is the current code I have:

```
<div class="authorAvatar">
    <img src="<?php echo $author->avatar;?>" style="width:auto;height:50px;">
    <a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $author->user_id;?>">
        <?php echo $author->username;?>
        <?php echo $author->points;?>
    </a>
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is the user's avatar being displayed, and then next to it, the username and the user's points directly below it. I have tried used the following CSS code:

```
.authorAvatar {
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    height:50px;
}

.authorAvatar a {
    display:inline;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

But the a href is centered in the div. I have also tried adding a `position:relative` to the `authorAvatar` and a `position:absolute;` and `top:0px;` to the a tag, but then the image is underneath the a href tag.

Here is a plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/9HVQ4U3UjjqaiHzlxqkO

How can I achieve something of this effect:

```
image     username
image     points
image
```

Comment: maybe use `display: inline-block` on `.authorAvatar a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap, try using the boostrap's css classes instead of your own css.

```
<img class="img-responsive pull-left"src="http://worldofdtcmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Apple-logo.jpg" style="height:50px">
<a class="pull-right"href="#">blabla</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.authorAvatar {
display:inline-block;
float:right;
height:50px;
}
.authorAvatar img{
display: inline-block;
}
.authorAvatar a {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="authorAvatar">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/" style="width:auto;height:50px;">
<a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $author->user_id;?>">
    <?php echo $author->username;?><br>
    <?php echo $author->points;?>
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether this effect fits what you need.

http://plnkr.co/edit/bdzuVhgAqaP6Bi6pLqOW?p=preview

html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<div class="authorAvatar">
    <img src="http://worldofdtcmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Apple-logo.jpg" style="width:auto;height:50px;">
    <a href="profile.php?id=1>">
      <div>blahblahblah</div>
      <div>blahblahblah</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

css:

```
.authorAvatar {
    height:50px;
}

.authorAvatar a {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```